# Return value destructed in operator*

Tags: c++, scope, return, operator-overloading

I'm creating a multiplication operator overload. It's declared like this:

```
T operator*(const T & right);
```

It creates a local *T* object, calculates its values and returns it. The problem is that when it's getting returned it seems that it goes out of scope and its destructor is being called. AFAIK it shouldn't happen, because a return statement should create a copy. I'm not making any references to it; the object contains dynamically allocated memory, but it should be handled by an assignment operator which I made. So I've a line like this:

```
t1 = t2 * t3;
```

where *t1*, *t2* and *t3* are *T* objects.

I've used my debugger and the local temporary *T* object inside `operator*` is fine, but the returned one lacks the dynamically allocated content.

What came into my mind is that the return statement does not copy my object correctly, because it didn't copy the dynamically allocated content because of lack of copy constructor. So I made a copy constructor like this:

```
T(const T & arg)
{
    *this = arg;
}
```

so it would use my assignment operator. And that's when things started getting weird. I was getting stack overflow (almost) every time when calling the copy constructor. And when debugging it seems that it didn't even call the assignment operator. What could be wrong?

Comment: Whatever you described in words obviously is not coded correctly.  So please post a [mcve].

Comment: Look up the "rule of three" or (if using C++11 or later) the "rule of five".   What you describe, with a class that is dynamically allocating some resource, is a typical symptom of not following those rules ... when you need to.

Comment: Generally a copy-ctor should not call the operator=, but rather have its own implementation. The reason is that a copy-ctor is initializing a new instance while an operator= is destroying an existing instance and copying from another existing object. My guess is that your operator= is merely assigning the allocated memory to 'this", (so now you have two instances pointing at the same memory) and when the right-hand-side goes out of scope, the allocated memory gets properly deleted. Now, you're left with a instance that has a dangling pointer to deleted  memory. Post your operator= code.

Comment: Also, why are you implementing operators that will return copies if you have not thoroughly tested your class's copy semantics?  Only write operators that return values once you've written and tested the foundations of your class.  You're blaming `operator *`, but that is not the problem.  The problem is that your class copying code is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for replies. The **rule of 3/5** was the issue. Also I had a method for data allocation, which didn't check if there was data allocated earlier, before cleaning it up. **SOLVED** :)